# custom @font-face does not load in chrome (chrome custom fonts not rendering)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

custom `@font-face` does not load in chrome(chrome custom fonts not rendering) Using custom fonts using CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'gotham-rounded-medium';
    src:url('fonts/gothumrounded_medium/gotham-rounded-medium.eot');
    src:url('fonts/gothumrounded_medium/gotham-rounded-medium.eot?#iefix')format("embedded-opentype"),
        url('fonts/gothumrounded_medium/gotham-rounded-medium.woff')format("woff"),
        url('fonts/gothumrounded_medium/gotham-rounded-medium.ttf')format("truetype"),
        url('fonts/gothumrounded_medium/gotham-rounded-medium.svg')format("svg");
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal
}

.custom_font{
   font-family:'gotham-rounded-medium', arial, sans-serif;
}
```

[image]

The texts are showing only when you resize the screen window.

**So please is there something that it can be done to solve this issue?**

Comment: We need more code. Can't debug from just this. But anyway, are you saying the text does not show at all? And how about other browsers?

Comment: Any resize, or to a particular size? Could there be a media-query taking effect when you resize?

Comment: A bit more of the "Styles" section in the screenshot would come in handy.

Comment: Today i tested with google font i don't show blank text. its work fine.  I think this is font load issue. gotham-rounded-medium.woff font size is 29kb. so let me know how i change font family after load all font file in javascript.

Comment: issue solved :)  using this reference - https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-loading.html

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was connected with multiple inclusion of the same @font-face made by different Angular 2 modules. Please see:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582198#c20

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is getting fixed in Chrome 59 if it is the same bug as listed here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=602968

Also - it's probably a better practice to only include font-face declarations once. We solved the issue by refactoring our CSS architecture and only including font-faces once.