# Rendering issue in Chrome due to @Font-Face

Tags: css, angular, less, angular2-template, angular2-components

I have a large scale application that is developed using Angular 4, there seem's to be an rendering issue exactly as mentioned in this post [Angular 2 Chrome DOM rendering problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766830/angular-2-chrome-dom-rendering-problems) 
.When I navigate using router from one component to another 
 , while this question has an answer already , I am still unable to solve this issue.

My Application structure is as follows :

```
app-home --- > app-main --- > app-sub --- > <router-outlet> (contents)
```

Each of this selector imports same mixin file which is used to `import @font-face` , while the solution mentioned in the above mentioned post suggests to use parent component and use ***ViewEncapsulation.NONE*** , I cant do the same thing since there is a usage of the imported font face in each of these components app-home, app-main,app-sub and subsequent childs as well. When I remove the @import statement from the .less files I get an exception like

```
Variable @helvetica-bold is undefined
```

Is there a workaround to make my texts appear normally in chrome when I route from one component to another.

Comment: Could you elaborate, how is it supposed to look and how is it looking in chrome right now instead?

Comment: The original text is present in the DOM , but hidden from view , just like the example given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766830/angular-2-chrome-dom-rendering-problems

Comment: Is it only the helvetica bold that has this issue, or other fonts as well?

Comment: All the fonts present in the @import mixins file

Comment: Can you confirm the fonts are all only importet once? Search for the font names in the whole project, including all plugins. Maybe some plugin is also importing the fonts at the same time.

Comment: app-home ,app-main and child component all import it at the same time , thats the issue I am not able to fix

Comment: I understand the issue now. I'll post an anwser you can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the font import is only called once.
Hence, you should remove all the font imports from the mixin file as you have already tried in your answer.

But, you also need to ensure the fonts themselves are still present once in your app where all views can access it. You probably have a file like 'app.less' or something similar, that contains styles that are available in all parts of your app. Cut the font-imports from your mixin, and instead place it in this file (make sure the path references are still valid, they might need to be adjusted). If you do not yet have such a file, you will need to create one and load it once on app start.

Comment: I have around 45 components and some common stylings have been customized for each component in its .less file , so I dont think placing them in single common file is feasible

Comment: You should only place the font import in a common file, not all stylings. Since this is a documented bug in Chrome, and it is indeed caused by importing the same font multiple times, there is currently no workaround besides removing the additional imports.

Comment: Also, didn't you say the files all use the same mixin? They probably don't all have their own copy of this mixin file, so you will only need to cut the import once from there, and paste it to the common file, not 45 times.